# android app using html and javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, ionic-framework

I create Simple android app using html,css,javascript & webview.
Using Ajax, I process the data from the asp.net server and display it on the client side page.
Is this method correct?
Would it be better to use ionic or react-nativ?

Comment: if your app preformed well with your approach then for sure there is no problem with it..